# Logic iterator in struts

Tags: struts

How to iterate a list, which is inside another list, using struts logic iterator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<logic:iterate id="new name for inner list" collection="outer array list name">
         <bean:write name="inner list name" />
 </logic:iterate>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code ,this will work for inner List

```
<logic:iterate id="parentObj" property="parentList" name="formname">
  <logic:iterate id="childObj" name="parentObj" property="childLstname">
    <bean:write name="childObj" property="childAttributeName" />
  </logic:iternate>
</logic:iterate>
```